# Activating the root user with a python script. (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, root

Okay, I've been working on a  pythonbased 'hacktool' with helps penetration testers install some basic tools on Mac.
Now most of these tools require a root user to be activated, so I need an easy way to activate the root user (On mac this can be done by 'passwd root' sadly that requires another input to be typed)

Need some help here guys, running low on time and the internet won't give me any helpful answers. :S

Comment: Great, if you add your answer in an answer text box and mark it accepted, you will get some points and those "lost souls" will be best served. It may seem strange, but it's actually encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command in OSX called 'dsenableroot' which did exactly what I wanted it to do. The command works like this:

```
dsenableroot -u yourusername -p yourpassword -r rootpassword
```

It does exactly what it is supposed to do, now I just need a workaround on the 'yourpassword' part, since I don't know the password of the Users computer. Will post updates here!